# Using conditional map function to transform array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of numbers, that I want to map into a new array of numbers.

```
let numbers= [1,3,5,10,11]
```

needs to be turned into

```
var result = [4,8,15,21,11];
```

i tried using ES6 shorthand syntax, to do it. But there is not really any coherence between the numbers, so i though a callback would be better

```
let numbers= [1,3,5,10,11]

const result = numbers.map(x => resultBinding(x))


function resultBinding(x){

}
```

now my issue here is that I don't want to try to avoid making a lot of if-statements to determinate each value.

Comment: what is the logic of 1 getting converted to 4 and so on?

Comment: This was an assignment, given y my teachers, there is no real logic behind it. I also think this is a strange task, since this has little relevance to an actual project..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate it with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Combine the current item, and the next item (or 0 if undefined):

```js
const numbers= [1,3,5,10,11]

const result = numbers.map((n, i) => n + (numbers[i + 1] || 0));
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `reduce` to keep track of the previous array value using the accumulator:

```
 const result = [];
 array.reduce((a, b) => (result.push(a + b), b));
 result.push(array.pop()); // add the trailing 11
```

Answer (score 3):

operation of result = [1+3, 3+5, 5+10, 10+11, 11]. last index of result is same as numbers array because there is no index after that.

```js
let numbers= [1,3,5,10,11];

let result = numbers.map((num, index)=> (index+1) >= numbers.length ? num : num + numbers[index+1])

console.log(result);
```